# Where to place the CSS file that i want to add for a Sitecore form field

Tags: sitecore-forms, css

I want to know where to place the CSS file that I want to add for a Sitecore form field. For the WFFM the path was `/sitecore modules/Shell/Web Forms` for Marketers/Themes.
I am using `Sitecore 9.1` and I have the form module working fine. But there are no Web Forms for Marketers folder.
Where should we place the custom CSS or script file for Sitecore Forms fields?

**Updating the question 06/10/2020**

I have placed my CSS file in below-mentioned path `/sitecore modules/Web/ExperienceForms/css`.
Custom CSS file name is **basicfield.css**  and the content of the class is as below:

.btn-testsuccesss
{

color: #fff;

background-color: hsl(93, 41%, 65%);

border-color: hsl(93, 41%, 45%);

}

adding the CSS in form field as below(also tried with direct CSS file name didn't work):

[image: adding the css]

But it is not reflecting, what am I missing? why is it not working?

Comment: Have you try adding the files at the path `website/sitecore modules/Web/ExperienceForms/css`? You may need to create the folder `css` if not present. Then, just add the css file name in the field of the main form

Answer (score 2):

To start using custom styles and scripts in your forms:

In the Content Editor, navigate to sitecore/Forms, click the form that you want to add a script or style to and, in the Scripts or Styles field, add the name of your custom script or style file.

[image]

Add your custom style or script file to one of the following folders:

Scripts : /sitecore modules/Web/ExperienceForms/scripts

Styles: /sitecore modules/Web/ExperienceForms/css

Answer (score 1):

You can below link for Sitecore Form styling - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/add-styles-and-scripts-to-sitecore-forms.html

Sitecore Forms uses css and script files located in: `<siteroot>/sitecore modules/Web/ExperienceForms`

So for css you can go to path - `<siteroot>/sitecore modules/Web/ExperienceForms/css`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in the marketing forms?

[image: css]